Armature and rig break after exporting as FBX and importing back into Blender or any other software
The rig and armature I use work perfectly in .blend files and can be animated.
However, when I export my model as .fbx, the bones change their positions and the model becomes impossible to animate or use in any projects. How can I export my model in a way that does not break the armarure?


